# How to fix screen tear?

Tags: intel-graphics, screen, gpu-driver

I have a 4k screen with Intel 520. When I was a video in full screen I notice a lot of screen tear. I specifically noticed this on YouTube. I use the Google Chrome Browser.

Things I have tried:

- CompizConfig Settings Manager
- [Screen tearing while watching video](https://askubuntu.com/questions/88198/screen-tearing-while-watching-video)
- [Screen tearing with Intel graphics](https://askubuntu.com/questions/921755/screen-tearing-with-intel-graphics)

Comment: What resolution are you watching the videos at? Do you have hardware acceleration enabled in Chrome settings?

Comment: Typically they run at 1080p and I have hardware acceleration disabled.

Comment: Make sure the `intel-microcode` package is installed, and enable hardware acceleration, and see if it fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have the `intel-microcode` package installed, and *Hardware acceleration* enabled in Chromium (or Google Chrome if using it instead), to improve performance of HTML5 video in the browser, such as when watching on YouTube.